# R Stepwise creating Error in is.data.frame(data) : object '.' not found

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I've been trying to use stepwise regression on this data, but it comes up with the above error each time, any advice why this is happening?

```r
> lm_life_expectancy_1 <- country_tidy %>%
  filter(Year=="1999", 
         !is.na(`Life expectancy at birth, total (years)`)) %>%
  lm(formula =`Life expectancy at birth, total (years)`~ 1)
summary(lm_life_expectancy_1)

step(lm_life_expectancy_1, scope = ~ `Age at first marriage, female`+ 
       `Age at first marriage, male`+
       `Birth rate, crude (per 1,000 people)`+
       `Births attended by skilled health staff (% of total)`+
       `Death rate, crude (per 1,000 people)`+
       `Fertility rate, total (births per woman)`+
       `GNI per capita, Atlas method (current US$)`+
       `Health expenditure per capita (current US$)`+
       `Health expenditure, total (% of GDP)`+
       `Hospital beds (per 1,000 people)`+
       `Incidence of HIV (% of uninfected population ages 15-49)`+
       `Incidence of tuberculosis (per 100,000 people)`+
       `Literacy rate, adult total (% of people ages 15 and above)`+
       `Mortality rate, adult, female (per 1,000 female adults)`+
       `Mortality rate, adult, male (per 1,000 male adults)`+
       `Mortality rate, infant (per 1,000 live births)`+
       `Physicians (per 1,000 people)`+
       `Population growth (annual %)`+
       `Population, female`+
       `Population, male`+
       `Population, total`+
       `Rural population`+
       `Rural population growth (annual %)`+
       `Urban population`+
       `Urban population growth (annual %)`)
```

The data does have NA's could that cause it?

[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOiZY.png)

trying to run a stepwise regression but this error appears after the first iteration of the step formula, I cant understand what is causing it.

Comment: Could you please include the data sample in a text format (either using `dput()` or by cutting-and-pasting tabular data into a code block)  rather than as a link to an image?

Comment: My guess would be it's not the NAs (that would give an error "number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?") but *possibly* the non-standard (backtick-protected) variable name? But I can't reproduce the problem easily ...

Comment: I agree with Ben that the `NA`s are not a likely culprit, but it's also a simple check: run the models on `country_tidy |> na.omit() |> ...` to remove them all. If the error goes away, then the `NA`s are the problem. If it's still there, you have another problem.